# How to get complex model using room?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have a UI model called `CourseUiModel` that I use in my ViewModel.

```
data class CourseUiModel(
        val Id: String,
        val Title: String,
        val Subtitle: String,
        // Author is missing
        val lessonModels: List<LessonUiModel>,
)

data class LessonUiModel(
        val Id: String,
        val Name: String,
        val topicModels: List<TopicUiModel>,
)

data class TopicUiModel(
        val Id: String,
        val Name: String
)
```

I have 3 tables on the local database called `Course`, `Lesson`, and `Topic`. Entity classes are:

```
    @Entity
    @Parcelize
    data class Course(
            @PrimaryKey
            val Id: String,
            val Title: String,
            val Subtitle: String,
            val Author: String,
    ) : Parcelable {}
    
    @Entity(indices = [Index(value = ["CourseId"])],
            foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
                    entity = Course::class,
                    parentColumns = arrayOf("Id"),
                    childColumns = arrayOf("CourseId"),
                    onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)])
    @Parcelize
    data class Lesson(
            @PrimaryKey
            val Id: String,
            val Name: String,
            val CourseId: String,
            val OrderInCourse: Int,
    ) : Parcelable {}
    
    @Entity(indices = [Index(value = ["LessonId"])],
            foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
                    entity = Lesson::class,
                    parentColumns = arrayOf("Id"),
                    childColumns = arrayOf("LessonId"),
                    onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)])
    @Parcelize
    data class Topic(
            @PrimaryKey
            val Id: String,
            val Name: String,
            val LessonId: String,
            val OrderInLesson: Int,
    ) : Parcelable {}
```

How do I map the query I get from room to this object? What I currently have is the following:

```
@Query("""SELECT *
    FROM Course
    JOIN Lesson ON Course.Id = Lesson.CourseId
    JOIN Topic ON Lesson.Id = Topic.LessonId
    WHERE Course.Id = courseId
    ORDER BY Lesson.OrderInCourse, Topic.OrderInLesson ASC""")
fun getCourseModel(courseId: String): LiveData<CourseUiModel>
```

When I try to run this I get the following error

```
error: The columns returned by the query does not have the fields [lessonModels] in com.albiders.albiders.ui.Courses.ui_models.CourseUiModel even though they are annotated as non-null or primitive. Columns returned by the query: [Id,Title,Subtitle,Author,Id,Name,CourseId,OrderInCourse,Id,Name,LessonId,OrderInLesson]
```

The error makes sense but I don't know how to properly do this.

Comment: Have `getCourseModel()` return a `LiveData<Course>`. Or switch `CourseUiModel` to [use `Relation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Relation). See also https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you want to use `@Relation` to build the Arrays so

**CourseUiModel** could be :-

```
data class CourseUiModel(
    val Id: String,
    val Title: String,
    val Subtitle: String,
    // Author is missing

    @Relation(entity = Lesson::class,entityColumn = "CourseId",parentColumn = "Id")
    val lessonModels: List<LessonUiModel>
)
```

and

**LessonUiModel** could be :-

```
data class LessonUiModel(
    val Id: String,
    val Name: String,
    @Relation(entity = Topic::class,entityColumn = "LessonId",parentColumn = "Id")
    val topicModels: List<TopicUiModel>
)
```

However, I believe that the above will not produce the results that you want. This is because the ORDER BY clause (Order of Lesson and Order of Topic) will not be honoured as Room, I believe, builds the child objects from the topmost parent (Course) object so the ORDER BY is only relevant to the top most object (Course).

In fact you can just use `("SELECT * FROM Course WHERE courseId = :courseID:)` and it will extract the same data.

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me the following error: Relations should either be [at]Entity or [at]DatabaseView

Comment: @M.Azyoksul for testing I don't use LiveData hence the List<.....> that could be the issue. However, the above was tested and worked fine without LiveData. P.S. you did note that I referred to the **Entity** and NOT the respective UiModel in the @Relation?

Comment: YOU ARE RIGHT! I totally disregarded the "entity = Lesson::class" part. You are a lifesaver.